# CORS pode ser configurado para Websocket?

Tags: websocket, cors

Tenho uma aplicação que precisa se comunicar via WebSocket com dois servidores cada um em seu próprio domínio independente.

É possível configurar CORS para permitir esta comunicação dupla e simultânea ?

Answer (score 7):

As informações sobre WebSockets e a política de mesma origem são escassas (e [conflitantes](http://www.ctovision.com/2013/05/websockets-meets-security/)), mas tudo indica que eles **não** estão sujeitas a essa política, e portanto **podem ser usados** para se comunicar com outros domínios.

De acordo com a [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#WebSocket_protocol_handshake), o protocolo de *handshake* dos WebSockets exige que seja enviado um *header* `Origin` junto à requisição, e o servidor deve então decidir se aceita ou não uma conexão com aquela origem. Parece também que [há diferenças](http://www.christian-schneider.net/CrossSiteWebSocketHijacking.html) entre se tentar uma conexão usando o protocolo `http(s)` ou o protocolo `ws(s)` - e o uso de um ou outro tem implicações na segurança da aplicação (i.e. no caso do http pelo menos, os cookies de autenticação são enviados).

Comment: obrigado @mgibsonbr. Como preciso disso em ambiente especifico (dois servidores Tomcat 7 diferentes) você tem alguma ideia de como posso testar se funciona, ou seja como posso abrir duas requisições HTTP na mesma seção do browser ? Tenho de usar iframes ?

Comment: Não tenho experiência suficiente pra dizer com certeza, mas não seria uma simples questão de criar o web socket passando o domínio desejado? Na sua página: `var ws1 = new WebSocket("ws://www.example.com/socketserver"); var ws2 = new WebSocket("ws://www.example.net/socketserver");`. Não sei como seria usando o protocolo `http` em vez de `ws`, mas deve funcionar igual. A propósito, esqueci de mencionar na resposta, o `Origin` quem seta é o browser, não o código JS.

Comment: Quando passa via HTTP(s) o servidor usa um fallback de comunicação PushStream que se comporta de forma similar ao protocolo ws.